# Assigning json output to array var

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, getjson

I've a jquery function that use a json. The json output, I want to put into an array and after I will use the array for to fill a table (the code for fill the table  is complex, I'm going omit  it). The below code don't work, but if I assign directly the json output to array (json output) it works.

Server-side (table.menus.php):

```
Editor::inst( $db, 'menus', 'id' )
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'seccion' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'descripcion' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'precio' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' )
    )
    ->process( $_POST )
    ->json();
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var data = [];
    data = $.getJSON("table.menus.php", function(json) {
        data = json;
    });
```

The html code works if instead to use the above code:

```
data = json;
```

I assign data array variable (copy and paste the json output from firebug) as below:

```
data = [{
    "DT_RowId": "row_1",
    "seccion": "Primeros",
    "descripcion": "paella valenciana con bogavante y cigalas",
    "precio": "189"
}, {
    "DT_RowId": "row_2",
    "seccion": "Segundos",
    "descripcion": "cocido completo",
    "precio": "99"
}, {
    "DT_RowId": "row_3",
    "seccion": "Primeros",
    "descripcion": "Raviolis al presto",
    "precio": "65"
}, {
    "DT_RowId": "row_4",
    "seccion": "Segundos",
    "descripcion": "Chuleton de buey",
    "precio": "60"
}];
```

Comment: `getJSON` is an asynchronous function. execute your code on result event (after `function(json){`)

Comment: what does `consoke.log(json)` before line `data = json;` gives? I suspect json will be an `Object` instad of `Array`..

Comment: @AdityaJain look what he is doing `data =$.getJSON(...` this is the issue

Comment: .. I'm going to investigate about Peter  said. Any help more  or code sample will be welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the JSON output give a object (array) , and really I need to handle as variable. The solution was as than simple as assign the JSON output  to a variable, and now It work!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("../php/platos.php", function(data){
    for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
    data = data['data']; //    assing array output (object) to var. easy and work!
```